# Why Do i receive "Singleton variable" warning and incorrect result?

Tags: prolog

i'm writing a simple function in prolog (beginer). Function calculates a specific type of quadratic equation (but this is not important, calculations are correct).

```
liniowa(A, B, R, W) :-
    Delta is 4*A*A*R - 4*B*B + 4*R,
    ( Delta < 0
        -> false
        ; ( Delta == 0
        -> X is -B/(2*A),
           Y is A*X + B,
           W = punkt(X, Y)
        ; X1 is (-B + sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
          Y1 is A*X1 + B,
          X2 is (-B - sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
          Y2 is A*X2 + B,
          writeln(X1), writeln(Y1), writeln(X2), writeln(Y2),
          W = punkt(X1, Y1) ;  W = punkt(X2, Y2)
        )
    ).
```

When i run this function, i receive warnings:

```
 Singleton variable in branch: X2
 Singleton variable in branch: Y2
```

In the result i receive strange things. **In *writeln(X2), writeln(Y2)* everything is ok, but then there is sth strange in *punkt(X2, Y2)*:**

```
1.4142135623730951
1.4142135623730951
-1.4142135623730951
-1.4142135623730951
W = punkt(1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951)
W = punkt(_1344, _1346)
```

What's happening? How should I make it?

Comment: That "something strange in `punkt(X2,Y2)`" are unbound variables, which, when Prolog needs to print them are given random names `_XXXX`. In effect, there is no data there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of `->/2` is horrendous at the best of times. That no official better syntax has been developed in 30 years is a sad statement, but of what? I won't say anything more about this.

It is best to separate out the program parts into separate predicates.

(A further refinement could be to separate out the case "Delta == 0" into a dedicated `delta_positive(A,B,W)`, thus avoiding having to make a decision on `delta_positive/4` and thus cutting and guarding.

```
liniowa(A, B, R, W) :-
    Delta is 4*A*A*R - 4*B*B + 4*R,
    ( Delta < 0 -> false ; delta_positive(Delta,A,B,W) ).
    
delta_positive(0,A,B,W) :-
   !,                         % commit to this clause
   X is -B/(2*A),
   Y is A*X + B,
   W = punkt(X,Y).
           
delta_positive(Delta,A,B,W) :-
   Delta \== 0,              % superfluous, but makes things clear
   !,                        % commit is also superfluous
   X1 is (-B + sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
   Y1 is A*X1 + B,
   X2 is (-B - sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
   Y2 is A*X2 + B,
   format("X1=~q, Y1=~q, Y2=~q, Y2=~q\n",[X1,Y1,X2,Y2]),
   (W = punkt(X1, Y1) ;  W = punkt(X2, Y2)).
```

This immediately shows that parantheses are missing around the expression:

`(W = punkt(X1, Y1) ;  W = punkt(X2, Y2))`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving it:-

```
liniowa(A, B, R, W) :-
    Delta is 4*A*A*R - 4*B*B + 4*R,
    ( Delta < 0
        -> false
        ; ( Delta == 0
        -> X is -B/(2*A),
           Y is A*X + B,
           W = punkt(X, Y)
        ;   X1 is (-B + sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
          Y1 is A*X1 + B,
          X2 is (-B - sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
          Y2 is A*X2 + B,
          writeln(X1), writeln(Y1), writeln(X2), writeln(Y2), 
          W = punkt(X1, Y1) ); X2 is (-B - sqrt(Delta)) / (2*A),
          Y2 is A*X2 + B, W = punkt(X2, Y2)
        ).

?-liniowa(2, 3, 4, W).
0.9083123951776999
4.8166247903554
-2.4083123951777
-1.8166247903553998
W = punkt(0.9083123951776999, 4.8166247903554)
W = punkt(-2.4083123951777, -1.8166247903553998)
```

I believe that in your code the calculation is being done in the previous step, that's why it is unable to pick it in the last case.